# gradient text in css with text shadow

Tags: html, css

Is there anyway to use this text gradient method and also have a drop shadow on the text.
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/gradient-text/

When I set my dropshadow like

```
text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #000;
```

Then it messes up my text gradient because the background is set to transparent.
Does anyone know of a solution to this for webkit browsers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I combined CSS text-shadow and "background-image: -webkit-gradient"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802218/how-do-i-combined-css-text-shadow-and-background-image-webkit-gradient)

Answer (score 37):

You can combine with `filter: drop-shadow` CSS property that will make the trick.

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 72px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#eee, #333);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  filter: drop-shadow(2px 2px #333);
}
```

```html
<h1>Example</h1>
```

Answer (score 13):

**updated**

Found a solution for you, 
only problem is it requires the html to have a attribute.

http://jsfiddle.net/2GgqR/2/

```
h1 {
  font-size: 72px;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#eee, #333);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  position:relative;  
}

h1:after {
  background: none;
  content: attr(data-text);
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #000;
}
```

original is here :)
http://viget.com/inspire/background-clip-text-shadow-gradients

**updated link** *from comments*
http://jsfiddle.net/2GgqR/5/

*here I added the background color of the background to the :after*

```
h1:after {
  background: #f3f3ee;
}

.background{
    background-color: #f3f3ee;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Hi Karl this works great until you try to have a wrapper div around it which I need to have a background image behind it all. see my updated fiddle with just a background color wrapper around it. http://jsfiddle.net/2GgqR/3/

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out a solution which does not use `filter` and `z-index`. This can be used if you have a background or a foreground:

```
h1 {
    position: relative;
}

h1::after {
    background-image: linear-gradient(#f00, #fcc);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    content: attr(data-content);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

h1::before {
    text-shadow: #000 1px 1px 2px;
    content: attr(data-content);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Effect: https://jsfiddle.net/m9dtf6po/2/

Of course, since I am using `::before` and `::after`, an attribute is needed, but the attribute can be shared. The problem of using `z-index` is that:

- If there are any elements behind the layer, the shadow will disappear (see https://jsfiddle.net/m9dtf6po/3/); or
- If there are any elements in front of the layer, the text will show in front of those elements (see https://jsfiddle.net/m9dtf6po/4/).

This was the problem I faced when I did have a background and a foreground sandwiching my text, as in the following image:
[image]

The text `S+` needs to be on top of a bar, but on top of all things there can be a box. I actually found this post and tried Karl's solution but the shadow disappeared behind the bar.

Answer (score 0):

Since some browsers didnt get the "clipping" rule I needed to find a way to create a gradient using just text shadow. So I managed to do it repeating the word and using color transparent .
Check the result here

HTML

```
<h2 class="points">
  <p><span class="text">REPEAT THIS WORD</span><span class="gradient">REPEAT THIS WORD</span><span class="gradient">REPEAT THIS WORD</span></p>
</h2>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
  background: black;
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.points {
  font-size: 2.8em;
  padding: 0 0.2em 0 1em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}
.points p {
  position: relative;
}
.points span {
  width: 100%;
}
.points span.text {
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  text-shadow: -2px 2px 0 #882b06, 2px 2px 0 #882b06, 2px -2px 0 #882b06, -2px -2px 0 #882b06;
}
.points span.gradient {
  color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
}
.points span:nth-child(2), .points span:last-child {
  color: transparent;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.points span:nth-child(2) {
  bottom: 0;
  text-shadow: 0 -0.33em 2px #fbe8a1;
  height: 0.8em;
}
.points span:last-child {
  bottom: 0.2em;
  text-shadow: 0 -0.55em 3px #ecb752;
  height: 0.4em;
}
```

https://codepen.io/kengreg/pen/JjrwLyL