# css switch shadow to the back of text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make some text look a little more 3D by adding a shadow to it, but I can not make the shadow appear behind the text, I have tried switching it around but it always break in weird ways, the shadow is either on top or totally messed up, here is a JS Fiddle with my exact code:
https://jsfiddle.net/2azp5z36/2/
As you see the problem is that the shadow is in front of the text instead of behind the text.

If you have a better suggestion than my current method I'm interested, as long as the end result look the same (except for the placement of the shadow, obviously),
**I only have 1 requirement:** the code for the solution **must** only use: HTML, CSS and/or JavaScript (preferably HTML5 & CSS3).

```css
h1.CV:before {
  /*text-align: center;*/
  background: none;
  content: attr(data-text);
  /*left: 0;*/
  position: absolute;
  text-shadow: 5px 5px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75); /*X,Y,BlurRadius,Color*/
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

h1.CV {
  /* http://jsfiddle.net/2GgqR/258/ */
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10em;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(red, orange, yellow);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  position:relative;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="CV" data-text="CV">CV</h1>
```

Comment: I think it is because of your `background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(red, orange, yellow);`. It may send the gradient to the back. I don't know how to solve it though.

Comment: This may give you a head start http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802218/how-do-i-combined-css-text-shadow-and-background-image-webkit-gradient

Comment: I think the same, but when I switch it, it becomes a black text with black shadow, I can't see if it fixes it or not because it's black on black, and even when I add the color gradient code to it it's still black.

Comment: @StephenC, Thanks! the answer to that question is the solution to my problem! How should I go about marking this tread as solved? Should I post a "special thanks" answer and include the answer from the other thread? Or do you want to make a comment and I mark it as the solution?

Answer (score 3):

It's because you're setting the `z-index` of the `h1`.  Just leave it as `z-index:auto` and the negative `z-index` should work as intended.  Note that based on the properties you're using, this effect [will only work in a few browsers](https://www.browserstack.com/screenshots/340108cd01f38ef16a88545a838cf479c958bd6f).

```css
h1.CV:before {
  /*text-align: center;*/
  background: none;
  content: attr(data-text);
  /*left: 0;*/
  position: absolute;
  text-shadow: 5px 5px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75); /*X,Y,BlurRadius,Color*/
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

h1.CV {
  /* http://jsfiddle.net/2GgqR/258/ */
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10em;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(red, orange, yellow);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  position:relative;
  z-index: auto;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="CV" data-text="CV">CV</h1>
```

Comment: Much easier way of doing it than mine.

Comment: Nice solution, but do you have any suggestions to what I should use instead that will work on more browsers?

Comment: @SebastianNorr Unfortunately, the issue is with `-webkit-background-clip`.  Clipping to text [isn't really well supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip#Browser_compatibility).  You could use an image instead or an SVG.

Comment: @SebastianNorr Something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10846504/text-with-image-background-in-svg-or-css#10853878

Comment: @Joseph Marikle SVG might work, but I can't include other files like a background.jpg or something, I need to define the graphics in the code.

Comment: @SebastianNorr SVG supports gradients.  Also, if you absolutely have to you can inline an image using base64 encoding.  It's basically encoding a file as base64 (alphanumeric characters with a few extra special characters) rather than as binary. It's not as efficient, so your file will be a little larger, but by storing the image data as text, it can be included in a CSS, HTML, JS, etc. file.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the text color to be transparent through `-webkit-text-fill-color` so that the background image can be used as the fill. The 'stacking order' means that the text itself is above anything in the background. The text-shadow is a property of the text, so it will also be above the background. I don't think this approach will work.

You'd probably need at least 1 more HTML element to make this work— would that be an acceptable solution?

Comment: How do you mean with another HTML element? like the solution from Sankarsh Makam above?

Comment: Yes, using a 2nd element, in his case he used a 2nd `h1` which depending on context might not be ideal (for example, SEO implications).

Answer (score 0):

Ok so, I hope this is what you wanted. I've tried to do it using 2 overlapping `<h1>` tags. Here is the [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sanky6/rcpqq696/). Here is the code:

```css
h1.CV:before {
  /*text-align: center;*/
  background: none;
  content: attr(data-text);
  /*left: 0;*/
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

h1.CV {
  /* http://jsfiddle.net/2GgqR/258/ */
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10em;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(red, orange, yellow);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  top: 20px;
}



h1.CV2:before {
  /*text-align: center;*/
  background: none;
  content: attr(data-text);
  /*left: 0;*/
  position: absolute;
  text-shadow: 5px 5px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75); /*X,Y,BlurRadius,Color*/
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

h1.CV2 {
  /* http://jsfiddle.net/2GgqR/258/ */
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10em;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(red, orange, yellow);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="CV2" data-text="CV">CV</h1>
<h1 class="CV" data-text="CV">CV</h1>
```

Comment: Aha, so you are just overwriting the shadow with another layer of gradient text?  smart.

Comment: I have less than 15 reputation so my vote is "recorded but hidden" and I would prefer to solve the problem than bypass it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your suggestions, they have been very helpful!

The final solution that I will use comes from: **Michael**
in this thread: [How do I combined CSS text-shadow and "background-image: -webkit-gradient"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802218/how-do-i-combined-css-text-shadow-and-background-image-webkit-gradient)
And special thanks to: **Stephen C**
For pointing that tread out for me.

Additional thanks to: **Joseph Marikle** & **Sankarsh Makam**
For interesting working code solutions.

The final solution that I will use comes from Michael above and looks like this:
https://jsfiddle.net/2azp5z36/6/

```css
h1 {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}

h1 div {
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(teal), to(black));
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    position: absolute; 
    width: 100%;
}
h1:after {
    text-shadow: 5px 5px 2px #000000;
    color: transparent;
}

.gradient-shadow:after {
    content: attr(title); /* Pulls the text from the 'title' attribute to make the shadow */
}
```

```html
<h1 class="gradient-shadow" title="Hello World">
  <div>Hello World</div>
</h1>
```